# What is the relationship between AGN and [OIII]

Tags: active-galaxy

I read that we can observe [OIII] from AGNs but what processes in AGNs produces these lines why we can use them to trace or tell if that galaxy is active or not?

Comment: This is a good question, but maybe you could show us what prior research you have done and didn't understand? There's googlable free lectures from reputable universities on the web about AGN line production, which would easily outcompete any answer given here on SE. So in general it is best to review this or any other material first and come up with questions based on that to post here.